# How to copy contents of a column in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I am trying to understand how Update query works in SQL. Basically I have a table called comments. The table has an "ID", "Comment_Name", "Creation_Date", and "Created_By".

What I want to do is update all the comments created by "User A" to be owned by "User B" in the same table.

How can I do this?

Sorry My bad here is the image of the table and its contents

[Please Click here for the data contents for user A of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPl7v.png)

[Please Click here for the data contents for user B of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm2zw.png)

So to clarify I want to Update all the contents that are owned by A to be Owned by B, A here could be owner_id lafunwtw and B here could be the user_id kvce8il7

Please Note here I have only one table with different owners. The main table is called posts

Comment: 'created by User A to be owned by User B' - ?? where is ownership column(s)?

Comment: Please post the table definition(s).

Comment: What's your exact question about this? Can you also limit your question to one database system, or is this meant to be generic?

Comment: Your title currently doesn't match your question: an Update query doesn't "copy" anything; as its name suggests, it _updates_ things, that is _changes their value_.

Comment: Post a very simple example. It's easier to see what you're after this way.

Comment: Please see the additional clarifications I have added, thanks @Mark

Comment: You should put this in a table, inlined within the question. Screenshots are not great - i think they are not compliant with the stackoverflow style guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a basic `update`:

```
update comments
   set created_by = 'B'
   where created_by = 'A';
```

That said, I'm not sure this is a good idea.  Overwriting the owner -- and forgetting the original owner -- seems like it might be dangerous for downstream applications.  For instance, if anyone summarized the number of comments created by 'B', then those numbers will suddenly change.

Comment: Hi @Gordon This does not work i tried the implementation SQL gave me an error ERROR:  permission denied for relation posts

Comment: @PratikPatel . . . Your question only mentions one table, `comments`, so that error makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

`UPDATE Comments SET Created_By = 'B' WHERE Created_By = 'A'`

As you can see, the update command will replace all line with "Created_By = A" with B.

Comment: A and B should be quoted,,

Comment: Thank you, that was a fast answer, my bad.